# How to simplify $5(2^k-1) + 5(2)^k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi i understand factorise by group but what about $5(2^k-1) + 5(2)^k$ ? What would happen? I know that there must be something to do with $5(2)^k$ because they are like terms, but i am unsure about how to factor them to make them together. Thank you!

Comment: Try expanding first to get $5 \cdot 2^k - 5 + 5 \cdot 2^k$.  If you combine the two $5 \cdot 2^k$ terms, what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

$5(2^k-1) + 5\cdot2^k=5\cdot2^k-5+5\cdot2^k=5\cdot2^{k+1}-5$

Comment: No. $5x+5x=10x$.

Comment: Why the downvote ???

Answer (score 0):

Writing $x=2^k$, your expression becomes

$$5(x-1)+5x$$ which can clearly be simplified to $$10x-5$$ or, replacing $x$ with $2^k$, to $$10\cdot 2^k - 5$$

this can be further simplified if we know $10=5\cdot 2$ to$$5\cdot 2\cdot 2^k - 5 = 5\cdot 2^{k+1} - 5$$

Comment: simplified to $10x -5$

Answer (score 0):

You have:$$5(2^k−1)+5⋅(2^k)  $$
Open the bracket $$5⋅2^k−5+5⋅2^k$$
take 5 common:
$$5(2^k+2^k)−5$$
It is $$5  (2 \cdot 2^k)-5$$
Substitute$$ 2^1 \cdot 2^k=2^{k+1}$$
You get: $$5(2^{k+1})-5$$
Or $$5(2^{k+1}-1)$$